# Flutter - App is getting crashed - Fatal Exception: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError - video_editor_sdk

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am picking video from gallery and trying to do some editing stuff on it using video_editor_sdk plugin.
When video is picked and I open it for editing, app is getting crashed as soon as

```
final result = await VESDK.openEditor(
        Video(path)
);
```

above method is called.

**Error**

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  663): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(  663): Process: com.example.video_edit, PID: 663
E/AndroidRuntime(  663): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
E/AndroidRuntime(  663):    at ly.img.android.pesdk.backend.model.state.manager.ImglyEventDispatcher.init(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(  663):    at ly.img.android.pesdk.backend.model.state.manager.SettingsList.<init>(SettingsList.java:88)
E/AndroidRuntime(  663):    at ly.img.android.pesdk.VideoEditorSettingsList.<init>(VideoEditorSettingsList.kt:32)
E/AndroidRuntime(  663):    at ly.img.flutter.video_editor_sdk.FlutterVESDK.present(FlutterVESDK.kt:133)
E/AndroidRuntime(  663):    at ly.img.flutter.video_editor_sdk.FlutterVESDK.onMethodCall(FlutterVESDK.kt:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(  663):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:258)
E/AndroidRuntime(  663):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
E/AndroidRuntime(  663):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:322)
E/AndroidRuntime(  663):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/AndroidRuntime(  663):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
E/AndroidRuntime(  663):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(  663):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
E/AndroidRuntime(  663):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8057)
E/AndroidRuntime(  663):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  663):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:620)
E/AndroidRuntime(  663):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1011)
E/AndroidRuntime(  663): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
E/AndroidRuntime(  663): │ Unable to find autogenerated SDK classes!                             │ 
E/AndroidRuntime(  663): │ This might be due to some Gradle mis-configuration.                   │
E/AndroidRuntime(  663): │ Please follow our Getting Started guide to properly setup the SDK.    │
E/AndroidRuntime(  663): │ If this issue persists,                                               │
E/AndroidRuntime(  663): │ please contact Support with information about your project structure. │
E/AndroidRuntime(  663): └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
E/AndroidRuntime(  663):    at ly.img.android.pesdk.backend.model.state.manager.ImglyEventDispatcher$Companion.genClassNotFound(ImglyEventDispatcher.kt:143)
E/AndroidRuntime(  663):    at ly.img.android.pesdk.backend.model.state.manager.ImglyEventDispatcher$Companion.access$genClassNotFound(ImglyEventDispatcher.kt:126)
E/AndroidRuntime(  663):    at ly.img.android.pesdk.backend.model.state.manager.ImglyEventDispatcher.<clinit>(ImglyEventDispatcher.kt:133)
E/AndroidRuntime(  663):    ... 16 more
I/Process (  663): Sending signal. PID: 663 SIG: 9
```

**Plugin**
[video_editor_sdk](https://pub.dev/packages/video_editor_sdk)

**Flutter SDK version**

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.7, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1555], locale en-US)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
[√] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
[√] VS Code (version 1.77.3)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability
```

Configurations are same as suggested in Readme file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the actual reason for it but you try
check your gradle version and try to update it if it is not updated one.